# R dplyr does not finish lagged date difference computation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame such as this:

```
> bp
Source: local data frame [6 x 4]

        date amount accountId type
1 2015-06-11  101.2         1    a
2 2015-06-18  101.2         1    a
3 2015-06-24  101.2         1    b
4 2015-06-11  294.0         2    a
5 2015-06-18   48.0         2    a
6 2015-06-26   10.0         2    b
```

It has 3.4 million rows of data:

```
> nrow(bp)
[1] 3391874
>
```

I am trying to compute lagged differences of time in days as follows using dplyr:

```
bp <- bp %>% group_by(accountId) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(date - lag(date)))
```

On my 8GB memory macbook, R crashes. On a 64GB Linux server the code is taking forever. Any ideas on fixing this problem?

Comment: Even the large memory linux server crashes after a while.

Comment: Maybe arithmetic on integers would be faster and less memory-intensive than on dates, like `c(NA,diff(as.integer(date)))`. You could also try the analogous code in `data.table`; I don't have a reason to think that it would give a huge speedup, but I think it's worth a try.

Comment: @Frank - on 3.4M rows and 1000 groups, `ave` can chew this down in less than a second on my machine: `with(dat, ave(as.numeric(date), accountId, FUN=function(x) x - c(NA,head(x,-1))))`

Comment: @thelatemail Okay. If that's so, I'd also expect the OP's code to manage. Must be a dplyr problem (being much worse than `ave`) or related to the OP's data, like not actually having a `date` column and invoking the function date or having some crazy format, eh? Anyway, I suppose it's hopeless for us to guess.

Answer (score 4):

No idea what has gone wrong over your way, but with `date` as a proper `Date` object, everything goes very quickly over here:

Recreate some data:

```
dat <- read.table(text="        date amount accountId type
1 2015-06-11  101.2         1    a
2 2015-06-18  101.2         1    a
3 2015-06-24  101.2         1    b
4 2015-06-11  294.0         2    a
5 2015-06-18   48.0         2    a
6 2015-06-26   10.0         2    b",header=TRUE)
dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date)
```

Then run some analyses on 3.4M rows, 1000 groups:

```
set.seed(1)
dat2 <- dat[sample(rownames(dat),3.4e6,replace=TRUE),]
dat2$accountId <- sample(1:1000,3.4e6,replace=TRUE)
nrow(dat2)
#[1] 3400000
length(unique(dat2$accountId))
#[1] 1000

system.time({
dat2 <- dat2 %>% group_by(accountId) %>%
  mutate(diff = as.numeric(date - lag(date)))
})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.38    0.03    0.40 

head(dat2[dat2$accountId==46,])
#Source: local data frame [6 x 6]
#Groups: accountId
#
#        date amount accountId type diff
#1 2015-06-24  101.2        46    b   NA
#2 2015-06-18   48.0        46    a   -6
#3 2015-06-11  294.0        46    a  -13
#4 2015-06-18  101.2        46    a    7
#5 2015-06-26   10.0        46    b    2
#6 2015-06-11  294.0        46    a    0
```

Comment: I see the problem. My data has 470,000 groups. I can run your code without a problem, and when I modify it to use 450,000 groups, same result (crash). :)

Comment: Try the `ave` code I pasted as a comment to your original question. It seems to work quite quickly here (~10s) - `dat2$out <- with(dat2, ave(as.numeric(date), accountId, FUN=function(x) x - c(NA,head(x,-1))))`